# Why program in C won't work on Windows?

Tags: c, linux, windows

I have a program written in Linux in C, and it works well on Linux platform, but it doesn't work in Windows. It compiles successfully in Windows, using Code Blocks(mingw32-gcc), but it doesn't work as expected, it simply throws an error and kills the program. How can I make it to work on Windows, Please help. This is the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, size, k = 2, ftab, sect = 3;

    char buf[512];
    char vbuf;
    int dev, fil_descr, off=0;

    fil_descr = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    assert(fil_descr > 0);
    read(fil_descr, buf, 512);
    close(fil_descr);

    printf("Bootsector file: %s\n" ,argv[2]);

    dev=open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    assert(dev > 0);
    write(dev, buf, 512);

    ftab = open("filetable", O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
    sprintf(buf, "{");
    write(ftab, buf, 1);

    for(i = 3; i < argc; i++)
    {   
        off = off + (k * 512);
        lseek(dev, off, SEEK_SET);
        fil_descr=open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
        assert(fil_descr > 0);
        size = 0;       

        while((read(fil_descr, &vbuf, 1))!=0) 
        {
            size++;
            write(dev, &vbuf, 1);

        }

        k = (size > 512)?2:1;

        sprintf(buf, "%s-%d," ,argv[i], sect);
        write(ftab, buf, strlen(buf));
        printf("Input file \'%s\' written at offset %d\n", argv[i], off);
        close(fil_descr);

        sect = sect + k;
    }

    sprintf(buf,"}");
    write(ftab, buf, 1);

    lseek(ftab, 0, SEEK_SET);
    read(ftab, buf, 512);

    lseek(dev, 512, SEEK_SET);
    write(dev, buf, 512);   
    close (dev);
    close(ftab);    
}
```

Comment: `but it won't work , it just eject error and program close.` but which error?

Comment: "it just eject error" What does that mean? Do you get an error message? Why is the content of this error message secret?

Comment: "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available"

Comment: Are you running your program with the expected arguments? You have some assertions in there ...

Comment: How do you run the application? Full command line, please.

Comment: in command prompt, i send expected arguments

Comment: We need to know what those arguments *are*.  Preferably, change your code (for debugging purposes) so that it uses constant strings rather than command-line arguments, and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a *C program not working under Windows* (although C is the programming language used).

What isn't woking is trying to compile a program using POSIX API functions (such as `open`, `read`, `write`) using a compiler targetting Win32. This includes the use of several headers that don't exist in this environment (which, if they existed, would declare functions that don't exist on the system).

You will either have to use a Unix compatibility layer (Microsoft used to sell that, not sure if they still do, also Cygwin might work), or use proper C, or use native Win32 API functions.

That said, it will also probably not work in the intended way if you switch to using the C standard library I/O funcitons or the native Win32 functions. The output "`Bootsector:`" suggests that you are trying something that will not work on the system drive at all, and only work with administrative privilegues on another disk.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug a problem like this, you should add some lines of code helping you to do so.

I changed the respective part of the program to

```
printf("Bootsector file: %s\n" ,argv[2]);
fil_descr = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
if (fil_descr < 0) {
    perror("open");
}

printf("fil_descr: %d\n", fil_descr);
assert(fil_descr > 0);
```

and became aware of the fact that the 2nd command line argument must be a file name of a file to be read.

If I specify it correctly, it works fine.

The 1st file is being written to, and the remaining arguments are file names to be read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both the headers are linux specific,

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: No, they are not linux specific.